# How Do I Turn On/Off X-Mouse in Tweak UI?

Tags: vb6

I'm attempting to create a VB6 executable (not sure of the proper syntax) that will toggle the X-Mouse option in Tweak UI under Windows 98SE.  Ideally, I would like to have two scripts - one that turns it off (regardless of its state) and one that turns it on (again, regardless of its state).

I have been able to open the TweakUI control panel with the code below.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Call Shell("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL tweakui.cpl", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

[image]

If possible, I would like it to do it without opening the TweakUI control panel.

As far as I can tell, changing the registry setting doesn't work as I would have to reboot the computer for that to take effect.

I have Registry Monitor 7.04 running.  It captures the following:

```
Path: C:\WINDOWS\RUNDLL32.EXE
Command Line: "C:\WINDOWS\RUNDLL32.EXE" "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\TWEAKUI.CPL", Tweak UI
Other: hKey: 0xC2A066F0
```

Honestly, I'm not sure how to move forward.

Not sure the best way to show progress on this, I'll just edit.

This code is very close.

```
Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias _
"SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, _
ByRef lpvParam As Any, ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long
Const SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING = 4097

'Click on this button to Activate XMouse
Private Sub Command1_Click()
SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING, 0, True, 0
End Sub

'Click on this button to Deactivate XMouse
Private Sub Command2_Click()
SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING, 0, False, 0
End Sub
```

Button 1 works correctly and Activates XMouse.  But button two does not deactivate it.

Comment: Windows 98?  I wonder if this would find better responses over at [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).  The `windows-98` tag there has more activity than the same tag does here on SO.

Comment: If TweakUI can do it, it's obviously possible. Find an old copy of RegMon that runs under 98, and see what TweakUI looks for and changes. You might have to broadcast a System Parameters Update to make it stick.

Comment: VB6 isn't "script."  You seem very confused.

Comment: I am very new to this.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I would also use process monitor to watch what TweakUI does, not just regmon. It may be able to capture system calls that do things other than just the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to all of the input.  I was able to solve this problem.

```
Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias _
"SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, _
ByVal lpvParam As Boolean, ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long
Const SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING = 4097


Private Sub Command1_Click()
retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING, 0, True, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING, 0, False, 0)
End Sub
```

In addition to the help here, I stumbled upon a few gems that gave me what I needed.
[Control the mouse speed under Windows 98 / 2000](https://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18576)
and
[Controling Active Window Tracking](https://microsoft.public.vb.winapi.narkive.com/gVzlggbw/controling-active-window-tracking)

A couple things of note.  I had to include this or else nothing happened:

```
Const SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING = 4097
```

Also, the 3rd parameter was

```
ByRef lpvParam As Boolean
```

Instead of

```
ByVal lpvParam As Boolean
```

I was passing a pointer to a pointer instead of a pointer to a value

Answer (score 3):

SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING is the parameter that does this.

`systemparametersinfo` is the function call that gets or sets settings like this. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa

There is sample code using `systemparametersinfo` that changes the wallpaper. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/changewallpaper.html